# What Javascript rich text editor will not break the browser's spellcheck?

Tags: javascript, spell-checking

I'm using TinyMCE in an ASP.Net project, and I need a spell check. The only TinyMCE plugins I've found use PHP on the server side, and I guess I could just break down and install PHP on my server and do that, but quite frankly, what a pain. I don't want to do that.

As it turns out, Firefox's built-in spell check will work fine for me, but it doesn't seem to work on TinyMCE editor boxes. I've enabled the gecko_spellcheck option, which is supposed to fix it, but it doesn't.

Does anybody know of a nice rich-text editor that doesn't break the browser's spell check?

Answer (score 4):

TinyMCE only goes out of its way to disable spell-checking when you don't specify the `gecko_spellcheck` option (i verified this with their example code). Might want to double-check your `tinyMCE.init()` call - it should look something like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "simple",
    gecko_spellcheck : true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Most rich text editors let you specify whether or not to disable the browser's spellchecker (as answered by others), with the exception of those running in Safari.

There is currently no way to programmatically disable the Safari spellchecker (as there is in FF and IE7+), so most rich text editors choose to let Safari do its own thing by leaving the browser in control of the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I know at least [yahoo!'s Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) will let you use the included spell checker in FireFox.

I also tested FCKeditor, but that requires the users to install additional plugins on their computer.